# redux, redux-thunk and re-render UI in theory

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am using redux, and redux-thunk and react in my project, This is not actual code but simplified version of code, so may be some syntax errors, but question is more about how it should work.

I have react wrapper using react-redux connect.

In my actions I am using redux-thunk as following -

```
return function (dispatch, state) {
      dispatch(oneAction);
      dispatch(secondAction);
      dispatch(thirdAction);
}
```

UI only render after thirdAction, which is good, but I could not figure out what tells the system that now render UI, as I am not returning data after thirdAction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Dispatching the action alone does not update the UI.

First, a reducer must listen to the dispatched actions and update the state of your application in the store.

Then, Your components (or views) must subscribe to the store and update their local state when the store is updated.

Comment: Yes each action is listen by store, and return new state and component is connected to store using connect from (react-redux)